# GET from back4app

Tags: python, python-3.x, parse-server, back4app

I pretty much copy and pasted from the parse documentation to get server information:

```
import json
import http.client
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('parseapi.back4app.com', 443)
conn.connect()
conn.request('GET', '/APP/users/ObjectID', '', {
       "X-Parse-Application-Id": 'AppID',
       "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": 'REST_API_kkey'
     })
result = json.loads(conn.getresponse().read())
print (result)
```

but i keep getting this result:

`{'message': 'Not Found', 'error': {}}`

Answer (score 0):

I think that the URL can be an issue, the code below worked for me

```
import json,http.client as httplib

connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('parseapi.back4app.com', '443')

connection.connect()
connection.request('GET', '/users', '', {
   "X-Parse-Application-Id": "AppID",
   "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "REST_KEY"
})
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())

print(result)
```

Let I know if it's working :)